# タイムゾーンの変更方法を教えていただけますか。

Tags: swift

下記のコードを実行すると、現在時間とずれたデータが保存されます。ネットで調べたところグリニッジ天文台の時間が記録されるみたいです。日本時間が保存されるようにタイムゾーンを変更する方法を教えていただけますか。

環境はSwift ４、MacBookProです。

現在時間保存用のコード

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class inputViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
     try! realm.write{
        self.diary.title = self.titleTextField.text!
        self.diary.body = self.bodyTextView.text
        self.diary.date = NSDate() // 問題の箇所
```

現在時間表示用のコード

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...

//セルの内容
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//再利用可能なセル
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
//セルに値を設定する
        let object = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description // 問題の箇所
...
}
```

Comment: 「書き出した時間」、「保存したデータ」、「記録されていない画面」など、何を意味するのか判りません。　意味が通る日本語で書いてください。

Comment: 了解しました。申し訳ありません。修正しました。

Comment: タイムゾーンを設定・変更する方法は基本ソフト(OS)によって異なります。お使いのシステムは何でしょうか？ニュージーランドやフィジーの標準時は、日本標準時より３時間進んでいます。３時間『ほど』というのは、システムの時計が正確でない可能性があります。定期的にntpで時刻合わせをしていますか？

Comment: ①と②はお互いに関係していない別の問題ではないでしょうか？それなら質問もそれぞれ別にした方がよいと思います。なお、segue.identifier は大文字小文字を区別しますので "cellsegue" と "cellSegue" は等しくありません。

Comment: 了解しました。先ず①の時間の問題について、方法を教えていただけますか。この問題となるコードは別な場所なのでコードを変更しました。‌​よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `NSDate`や`Date`は基準時からの秒数を保存しているだけで、タイムゾーンといったものはありません。日時の保存に`NSDate`, `Date`を使う場合には、表示の際にタイムゾーンを指定します。保存ではなく表示する方のコードをお示しください。

Comment: 了解しました。表示用のコードを掲載しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

コメントに書いたようにAppleのFoundationフレームワークの`NSDate`やそのSwift版の`Date`にはタイムゾーンを持ちません。通常、データ型を`NSDate`や`Date`とした場合、表示の際にタイムゾーンを反映させるようにします。

`NSDate`を表示用の文字列に変換しているのはこの行だけのようですね。

```
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description
```

残念ながら`description`プロパティでの文字列への変換は、現在のデバイスのタイムゾーン設定などを反映してくれません。(と言うか、きちんと動作が定義されていないので、バージョンによって全然違った表示になってしまう可能性すらあります。)

`NSDate`(または`Date`)型を表示用の文字列に変換する場合には`DateFormatter`を使用してください。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //...

    //`DateFormatter`のインスタンスを作ってプロパティに保持しておく
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        //デバイスの各種設定(タイムゾーン含む)に合わせ、システム標準の書式.mediumを使用する
        df.dateStyle = .medium
        df.timeStyle = .medium
        return df
    }()

    //...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //...
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description の行を以下のように変更
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: object.date as Date)
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

上記のコードでは、「日本時間」ではなく、デバイスに設定されている時間帯で時刻が表示されますが、デバイスの現在の設定によらず強制的に日本時間にする場合には、タイムゾーンを指定してください。

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    //デバイスの言語・12/24時間表示の設定に合わせるが、タイムゾーンだけ強制的に日本にする
    df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tokyo")
    //システム標準の書式のうち.mediumを使用する
    df.dateStyle = .medium
    df.timeStyle = .medium
    return df
}()
```

`dateStyle`, `timeStyle`を用いるとApple製の内蔵アプリっぽい日時の表示になりますが、逆にそれが気に食わない場合に、カスタム書式を指定する場合にはこんなコードになります。

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    //デバイスのタイムゾーンの設定に合わせ、書式だけ独自のスタイルにする
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")   //<-他のデバイス設定が書式に影響を与えないようにする
    return df
}()
```

タイムゾーンを強制的に指定したいのであれば、さっきと同じように`timeZone`プロパティを設定する1行を加えてください。

`DateFormattr`には他にも色々設定項目がありますが、「ios dateformatter」あたりで検索すれば良記事が多数ヒットしますし、その中には(英語記事を禁止にしていなければ)[Appleの公式リファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)なんかも見つかると思いますので、所望の表示形式となるよう調べて見てください。

---

ちなみに上記の方法で「表示の際にデバイスタイムゾーンを指定する」と言う方法では、日時を保存した後ユーザが移動してデバイスのタイムゾーンを変更すると、表示される日時がユーザの意識しているものとは異なってしまうかもしれません。

このような動作がいやなら、`NSDate`や`Date`を使わずに、データ型を`String`に設定して、「保存の際に(タイムゾーンを考慮して)日付を表す文字列に変換し、その文字列を保存する」ようにした方が良いかもしれません。ただ、この際にも`DateFormatter`は使用することになるでしょう。

Comment: 了解しました。大変勉強になりました。感謝します。